# Creating SBT Project in IntelliJ Ultimate 13.1.1 with Scala plugin gives no New > Scala object for src/main/scala?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm trying to get started with a quick Hello World application in Scala.

I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate 13.1.1. I've downloaded the Scala plugin. I've also downloaded the SBT plugin. The project SDK is Java 1.6.

I went ahead and created a new project. I selected `SBT Project`. The project is created fine. I notice that the `src/main/*` and `src/test/*` folders are created nicely.

When I right-click on the `src/main/scala` folder and try to create a new Scala object, there's no option to do so?! I tried to mark the directory as a sources root. Still, the issue persists. I'm given the option to create a Java file but not a Scala file.

What's going on?! I've been pulling my hair on this for the past two hours.

Comment: I always call from console `sbt "gen-idea no-classifiers"`. Of course you have to follow the instruction: [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea): add `addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.6.0")` to `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/build.sbt` or `PROJECT_DIR/project/plugins.sbt`

Comment: I prefer importing a project by pointing IntelliJ to the build.sbt file and accepting the Auto Update check box. Updates to your build.sbt then automagically updates your project.

Comment: Note: The Scala plugin for IntelliJ 13.x has built-in SBT support. You do not need to install an SBT plugin separately.

Comment: Thank you everybody, very useful tips!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in IntelliJ. Here is the answer to a bug report ([#25058](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/requests/25058)) I submitted:

> Andrey Dernov (JetBrains Support)
>   Mar 26 19:43
>
> Please see the respose from the developer:
>
> Hi Dave, the problem was (mostly) because of the uppercase letter
>   (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-6853). You can either use
>   lowercase project name, or wait for a new plugin build that fixes the
>   issue. Thank you for the bug report!

You can get around it by explicitly editing the Run -> Edit Configurations and adding the class that you want to run. Set the main class and delete the $ (for the object).

Comment: This has been fixed in more recent versions of IntelliJ and current Scala plugins.